# Identificar y separar carácteres de un string en PHP

Tags: php, php7

Tengo el siguiente string:

```
$variable = "/server1/carpeta1/archivo1";
```

Quiero separar el nombre del **servidor** y del **archivo** en dos variables distintas, que quede tal que así:

```
$server = "server1"
$archivo = "archivo1"
```

Mediante la función **explode** he conseguido separarla y me queda así:

```
$variable = "/server1/carpeta1/archivo1";

$identificador = explode("/",$variable) or die ("error");

$identificador[1] = "server1";
$identificador[2] = "carpeta1";
$identificador[3] = "archivo2";
```

Empieza en el 1 en vez de en el 0, no sé por qué

El problema está en que a la hora de sacar el nombre del archivo, si la ruta cambia (`"/server1/carpeta1/carpeta2/archivo1"`), el nombre estaría en la posición 4 en vez de en la 3.

PD: He intentado sacar el valor más alto de `$identificador` mediante `max($identificador)` pero tampoco funciona.

Gracias por leer.

Comment: Podrías identificar las carpetas como los campos que no tienen extensión

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `array` resultante de llamar a la función `explode` devuelve en cada uno de sus elementos lo que encuentre antes del separador hasta que se tope con otro separador (si lo hubiese). En tu caso el `array` si que empieza por `$identificador[0]` solamente que en esa posición no hay nada porque delante del primer separador `/` no hay nada. Ejemplo:

**PHP**

```
$variable = "/server1/carpeta1/archivo1";

$identificador = explode("/",$variable) or die ("error");

foreach ($identificador as $trozo) {
    echo 'Trozo: ' . $trozo . '<br>';
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
Trozo:
Trozo: server1
Trozo: carpeta1
Trozo: archivo1
```

La segunda parte de tu pregunta, podrías resolverla a través de la función `end()`, que nos devuelve el último elemento de un `array`.

**PHP**

```
$variable = "/server1/carpeta1/archivo1";

$identificador = explode("/",$variable) or die ("error");
$nombre_servidor = $identificador[1];
$nombre_archivo = end($identificador);


echo 'Nombre del archivo: ' . $nombre_archivo . '<br>';
echo 'Nombre del servidor: ' . $nombre_servidor;
```

**Resultado:**

```
Nombre del archivo: archivo1
Nombre del servidor: server1
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes realizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$path = "/server1/carpeta1/archivo1";

echo dirname($path); // /server1/carpeta1
echo basename($path); // archivo1
```

Comment: la respuesta es correcta, pero podrías agregar mas información para mejorar la calidad.